# Splunk query to get max indexed timestamp for a source type

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

I need Splunk query to get maximum indexed timestamp or latest indexed timestamp for a source type.

Please help as I am stucked here for quite long.

your help is highly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
| tstats latest(_time) where index=* by sourcetype
```

Comment: Hi Rich...you are bang on , above command providing me timestamp of any one of source type that is last indexed but I need to search timestamp of only particular source type i.e. source type="fields.json". can you help me with the query?

Comment: Just a simple variation of the same command.  `| tstats latest(_time) where index=* sourcetype="fields.json"`.  If you know the index name, use it instead of `*` for better performance.

Comment: Rich, When I am using your above command to search particular source type latest indexed timestamp, I am getting the result on Splunk web, but when I am using this command from linux using curl I am getting fatal error:

Comment: command-->

curl -k1 -u admin:prateeks https://Host:port/services/search/jobs/<SID>/results/ --get -d output_mode=csv

error-->  <msg type="FATAL">Error in 'TsidxStats': Missing field list after 'GROUPBY' or 'by' keyword</msg>

Comment: curl command I am using to get the SID is:-
curl -k1 -u username:pwd https://hostname:port/services/search/jobs -d search="|  tstats latest(_time) where index=* by sourcetype=fields.json"

Comment: Remove 'by ' from your query.

Comment: Thanks Rich...a huge shout out for you!